# XOM get Document to String

Tags: java, xml, xom

Suppose I have a String like this:

```
String from = "<time><day type="tt">ok</day><time>
```

Now what I would like to do is to create a XOM document and then return back something like:

```
String to = documentToString(document)
```

This string should have only `<day type="tt">ok parsed</day>`, not with `<time>..</time>`root element.

I have already created the XOM document but don't know what is the easy way to do the string-conversion part.

Comment: For followers, to get a document *from* a string try `    Builder builder = new Builder();    Document doc = builder.build(docStr, null);`

Answer (score 2):

The toXML() method is your friend:

```
import nu.xom.*;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class XomElementAsString
{
    public static void main( final String ... args )  throws Exception
    {
        String from = "<time><day type=\"tt\">ok</day></time>";
        Builder parser = new Builder();
        Document document = parser.build( new StringReader( from ) );
        Element child = document
            .getRootElement()
            .getFirstChildElement( "day" );
        System.out.println( child.toXML() );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<day type="tt">ok</day>
```

Comment: for followers, `toXML` spits it out as an XML representation, while `toString` does not, just lists the main header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath to get the day node:

```
Nodes nodes = document.query("/time");
```

You can get the string content of that node with

```
nodes[0].toXML();
```